# Check If Input is empty JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Hello**, There are simple problem in my code, I've put myself as a user, let's assume that if the user click on the space button (in keyboard), So What is the solution.

**Here my simple code:**

```js
var name = $('input#name').val(); // get the value of the input field
if(name == "" || name == " ") {
 $('#err-name').fadeIn('slow'); // show the error message
 error = true; // change the error state to true
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`$.trim`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) function to remove spaces

```js
var name = $.trim( $('input#name').val() ); // get the value of the input field
if(name == "") {
    $('#err-name').fadeIn('slow'); // show the error message
    error = true; // change the error state to true
}
```

Comment: Thank you mr.Gaby but I'd Like to know what this mean '$'?

Comment: `$` is the jQuery library object. (*You are already using it*)

Comment: i Know that if i need select element I using $('CSS Selector') :) :) But I Don't Know what is the difference between $ and $('')

Comment: @MoHamedHaSsn exactly. And jquery provides a method named `trim` that removes leading/trailing spaces from a string. To call that you use `$.trim( <string here> )`

Comment: Thank you for helping me MR.Gaby

Answer (score 1):

The .trim function in JavaScript removes leading and trailing spaces/new lines.  So, if the user just spams space bar, the name.trim() will remove all leading/trailing spaces, resulting in "" and that equals "".  Thus, your error code would show.

```
var name = $('input#name').val(); // get the value of the input field
if(name.trim() == "") {
    $('#err-name').fadeIn('slow'); // show the error message
    error = true; // change the error state to true
}
```